# Adding an exchange account to an iPhone

Tags: email, iphone, ios, exchange

After I upgraded my iPhone to iOS7 my Exchange account disappeared from the phone and I haven't found a way to add it back. Can somebody please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you open up "Settings" and choose "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" then under "Accounts" you should see "Add Account". Clicking on that allows you to choose to add an Exchange account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. You can also just edit the question directly to change it.

Comment: I wasn't **exactly**  sure I was right since it was so badly worded.